# Concatenating two hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have a number of hexadecimal numbers (20) which I am reading from a file, let's say like this,

```
0a 0b bc 05 50
```

I am reading them into two characters using,

```
fscanf(p,"%c",&a);
fscanf(p,"%c",&b);
```

where p is the file pointer and a and b are unsigned characters.
Now, I want to concatenate them and form a single number. Like this, I want to concatenate, each of the two hex numbers and finally calculate the sum of the 10 pairs since there are a total of 20 numbers. How can I do it using C++?

I tried using this,

```
unsigned int result = (a<<24) | (b<<16)
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the input file is a binary file, right ?

Comment: Is this a formatted text file, or are you just reading raw binary ?

Comment: Yes, it's a raw binary file.

Comment: So why not just read two consecutive bytes as a single `int16_t` ?

Comment: What is wrong with `fscanf(p,"%x",&n);` to read whole hex number?  `n` must be an int. it would save you all the conversions.

Answer (score 3):

**First**: If your file is a "raw" binary, then you shouldn't use `fscanf` to read it. Use `fread` instead:

```
fread( &a, sizeof( a ), 1, p );
fread( &b, sizeof( b ), 1, p );
```

**Second**: I don't know your goal, but I think, that you should "pack" readed bytes like this:

```
unsigned int result = ( unsigned int(a) << 8 ) | b;
```

Or you can read 16 bits at one into `unsigned short` variable and then swap it's bytes if it is needed:

```
unsigned short a;
fread( &a, sizeof( a ), 1, p );
unsigned int result = ( (a & 0xF) << 8 ) | ( a >> 8 ); // if you need swap
unsigned int result = a; // it you don't )))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is just raw binary data then you don't need to use formatted I/O or read individual chars - you can just read pairs of bytes as 16 bit integers and sum them, e.g.

```
uint32_t sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    uint16_t v;

    fread(&v, sizeof(v), 1, p):
    //NB: swap high/low bytes of `v` here if endianness is incorrect
    sum += v;
}
```

Comment: bumps up against endianness unless the file was created on the same platform.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add a note about endianness.

Comment: Although I doubt it, the file may be written in a chosen endianness. Thus the procedure would act differently depending on the system endianness

Comment: 1) IMHO it's not a good idea to name a variable readed from file `i`. It doubts with a cycle counter. 2) In your code calling `fread` is ends by `:` symbol but not `;`

Comment: This answer is a good example of how _not_ to solve the problem, see http://commandcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html, for example.

Comment: @JamesKanze: you may be right, but the question provides very little context, so it's not even clear whether there are likely to be any endianness issues.

Comment: @PaulR The question speaks of reading from an external file.  An external file has a specific format, which may not be the same as the internal format with the compiler version and options you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is text file containing hex numbers, like you showed in your example, you can read the whole hex number by using `"%x"` as format string.

```
int n;
while(!feof(p)){
   fscanf(p,"%x",&n);
   //no conversion needed...
}
```